# Why does it tells False, OpenCV python cv2

Tags: python, opencv

I've been doing a project involving a microscope, i'm developping some functions and when i try to invert the up pixels with the down pixels like if the height is 1000 the pixel with a y of 50 will change place with the pixel with an y of 950, and so for this function i did so i will give the code rn

```
# import the opencv library
import cv2
import tkinter as tk
import time

a = int(input("Choose which camera to use (Number) > "))
# define a video capture object
vid = cv2.VideoCapture(a)

width, height = int(input("Choose width (Max 1500) > ")), int(input("Choose height (Max 900) > "))

F1 = False
F2 = False

while True:
    # Capture the video frame
    liste = []
    liste2 = {"[0, 0, 0]": 0}
    maximum = []
    maxxx = ""
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (width, height))

    if F1:
        h, w, c = frame.shape
        for t in range(h):
            for y in range(w):
                for u in range(3):
                    frame[t][y][u] = 255 - frame[t][y][u]
    if F2:                   <--------------------------------- HERE
        frame = frame[::-1]

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)
    maxx = 0
    # Get the color that is the most on the screen
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('r'):
        for a in range(width):
            for b in range(height):
                liste.append(str(frame[a, b]))
        for i in liste:
            if i in liste2:
                liste2[i] += 1
            elif not i in liste2:
                liste2.update({i: 1})
        for i in liste:
            if maxx < liste2[i]:
                maxx = liste2[i]
        for i in liste:
            if maxx == liste2[i] and not maxx in maximum:
                maxxx = i
        print(maxxx)

    # Invert Image Colors
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('i'):
        if not F1:
            F1 = True
        if F1:
            F1 = False
        print(True)

    # Invert y pixels
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('g'): # <------- HERE
        if not F2:
            F2 = True
        elif F2:
            F2 = False
        print(F2)

    #Quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
# After the loop release the cap object
vid.release()
# Destroy all the windows
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

So because there is a sort of game loop, so when i am pressing the key g i am trying to switch from inverted to not inverted but when i do so the F2 value (the boolean to at the first <----- HERE) it always tells me False. Thanks for helping
PS : The answer is probably a dumb thing anyways

i just told it, but i am trying to make a bool go True when it's False and i activate it and when it's False it goes True but it always go False

Comment: why not just flip the boolean like this? `F1 = not F1`, same for `F2`

Comment: `0xff == ord('g')` is always False. You should use the result of waitKey. See vencaslac's answer how.

Comment: @pts please look up python syntax, operator precedence. what happened that caused you to make that mistake?

Comment: Indeed, it's equivalent to `if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('g'):`, which can be True.  See vencaslac's answer for calling `cv2.waitKey(1)` only once, and reusing the result.

Comment: @pts I don't need to. I am very familiar with OpenCV.

Answer (score 2):

the issue is that you are doing `cv2.waitKey(1)` multiple times in the same timestep, your code works but only if you spam the key because the keypress has to happen prior to the corresponding condition in each timestep, the more conditions/cases you have for the keypress the less likely it will be for it to precisely match.

you have to store the command in a variable so that you listen for the keypress once per timestep and then use the stored value in your conditions like this:

```py
    command = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if command == ord('i'):
       ...
```

this should work better

Answer (score -1):

> Why does it tells False,

The problem can be fixed.

Solution is to use `waitkey(0)` instead of `waitkey(1)`.

Snippet:

```
   # Invert Image Colors
    key = cv2.waitKey(0)
    if key == ord('i'):
        if not F1:
            F1 = True
        if F1:
            F1 = False
        print(True)

    # Invert y pixels
    if key == ord('g'): # <------- HERE
        if not F2:
            F2 = True
        elif F2:
            F2 = False
        print(F2)

    #Quit
    if key == ord('q'):
        break
```

Output:

```
Choose which camera to use (Number) > 0
Choose width (Max 1500) > 900
Choose height (Max 900) > 640
True    # this image is 90 degree ('i')
True    # this image turned upside('g')
```

Comment: Btw, pressing 'g' will turned image upside down and vice-versa.

Comment: suggesting to use waitKey(0) *instead of waitKey(1)* doesn't solve the issue but it ***introduces a new issue***: this will block the video (VideoCapture!) until a key is pressed. as long as that doesn't happen, no new frame will be read and displayed. that is contrary to OP's intent.

Comment: on questions regarding OpenCV, you have demonstrated remarkable consistency in getting answers wrong. perhaps it's time to face this.